# Keras: network doesn't train with fit_generator()

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm using Keras on the large dataset (Music autotagging with MagnaTagATune dataset). So I've tried to use fit_generator() fuction with a custom data generator. But the value of loss function and metrics doesn't change during the training process. It looks like my network doesen't train at all.

When I use fit() function instead of fit_generator() everything is OK, but I can't keep the whole dataset in memory.

I've tried with both Theano and TensorFlow backends

**Main code:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = models.FCN4()
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy', 'categorical_accuracy', 'precision', 'recall'])
    gen = mttutils.generator_v2(csv_path, melgrams_dir)
    history = model.fit_generator(gen.generate(0,750),
                                  samples_per_epoch=750,
                                  nb_epoch=80,
                                  validation_data=gen.generate(750,1000,False),
                                  nb_val_samples=250)
    # RESULTS SAVING
    np.save(output_history, history.history)
    model.save(output_model)
```

**class generator_v2:**

```
genres = ['guitar', 'classical', 'slow', 'techno', 'strings', 'drums', 'electronic', 'rock', 'fast',
        'piano', 'ambient', 'beat', 'violin', 'vocal', 'synth', 'female', 'indian', 'opera', 'male', 'singing',
        'vocals', 'no vocals', 'harpsichord', 'loud', 'quiet', 'flute', 'woman', 'male vocal', 'no vocal',
        'pop', 'soft', 'sitar', 'solo', 'man', 'classic', 'choir', 'voice', 'new age', 'dance', 'male voice',
        'female vocal', 'beats', 'harp', 'cello', 'no voice', 'weird', 'country', 'metal', 'female voice', 'choral']

def __init__(self, csv_path, melgrams_dir):

    def get_dict_vals(dictionary, keys):
        vals = []
        for key in keys:
            vals.append(dictionary[key])
        return vals

    self.melgrams_dir = melgrams_dir
    with open(csv_path, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='excel-tab')
        self.labels = []
        for row in reader:
            labels_arr = np.array(get_dict_vals(
                row, self.genres)).astype(np.int)
            labels_arr = labels_arr.reshape((1, labels_arr.shape[0]))
            if (np.sum(labels_arr) > 0):
                self.labels.append((row['mp3_path'], labels_arr))
        self.size = len(self.labels)


def generate(self, begin, end):
    while(1):
        for count in range(begin, end):
            try:
                item = self.labels[count]
                mels = np.load(os.path.join(
                    self.melgrams_dir, item[0] + '.npy'))
                tags = item[1]
                yield((mels, tags))
            except FileNotFoundError:
                continue
```

To prepare arrays for fit() function I use this code:

```
def TEST_get_data_array(csv_path, melgrams_dir):
    gen = generator_v2(csv_path, melgrams_dir).generate(0,100)
    item = next(gen)
    x = np.array(item[0])
    y = np.array(item[1])
    for i in range(0,100):
        item = next(gen.training)
        x = np.concatenate((x,item[0]),axis = 0)
        y = np.concatenate((y,item[1]),axis = 0)
    return(x,y)
```

Sorry, if the style of my code is not good. And thank you!

**UPD 1:**
I've tried to use `return(X,y)` instead of `yield(X,y)` but nothing changes.

**Part of my new generator class:**

```
def generate(self):  
    if((self.count < self.begin) or (self.count >= self.end)):
        self.count = self.begin
    item = self.labels[self.count]
    mels = np.load(os.path.join(self.melgrams_dir, item[0] + '.npy'))
    tags = item[1]
    self.count = self.count + 1
    return((mels, tags))

def __next__(self):   # fit_generator() uses this method
    return self.generate()
```

**fit_generator call:**

```
history = model.fit_generator(tr_gen,
                              samples_per_epoch = tr_gen.size,
                              nb_epoch = 120,
                              validation_data = val_gen,
                              nb_val_samples = val_gen.size)
```

**Logs:**

```
Epoch 1/120
10554/10554 [==============================] - 545s - loss: 1.7240 - acc: 0.8922 
Epoch 2/120
10554/10554 [==============================] - 526s - loss: 1.8922 - acc: 0.8820 
Epoch 3/120
10554/10554 [==============================] - 526s - loss: 1.8922 - acc: 0.8820 
Epoch 4/120
10554/10554 [==============================] - 526s - loss: 1.8922 - acc: 0.8820 
... etc (loss is always 1.8922; acc is always 0.8820)
```

Comment: Before `for count in range(begin, end)`, you may shuffle your data.

Comment: @Ladislao I also facing the same issue. Can you please tell me what procedure you followed to solve the problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: @prasanna, As mentioned in comments to the best answer I've just placed more elements in a batch and it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem as you with the yield method. So i just stored the current index and returned one batch per call with the return statement.

So I just used `return (X, y)` instead of `yield (X,y)` and it worked. I am not sure why this is. It would be cool if someone could shed a light on this.

Edit: 
You need to pass in the generator to the function not only call the function. Something like this:

```
model.fit_generator(gen, samples_per_epoch=750,
                                  nb_epoch=80,
                                  validation_data=gen,
                                  nb_val_samples=250)
```

Keras will call your __next__ function, while training on the data.

Comment: I've tried, but nothing changes. Please check if I understood you correctly (my code with `return` statement is in the end of the main post). Thank you!

Comment: Should work when passing the generator like this. If not could you post your error message?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing my generator into `fit_generator` function like this. There is no exceptions or errors. The problem is that the value of the loss function isn't changing during the training process (I've added logs to the main post). It looks like the network doesn't refresh its weights. It couldn't be a mistake in the model, because `fit` function (with arrays instead of generators) works fine.

Comment: Your batch size this way is 1. Try passing more elements per iteration to the model. This means having your next method return for example 32 elements. Maybe your intra class differences are too large to use 1 as a batch_size.

Comment: Were you able to find solution to your problem ?

Comment: now fit_generator is DEPRICATED, use .fit with generator as an argument

Answer (score 0):

In method 'generate', there is a while statement.

```
def generate(self, begin, end):
    while(1): # this
        for count in range(begin, end):
            try:
                # something
                yield(...)

            except FileNotFoundError:
                continue
```

I think this statement is not needed, so

```
def generate(self, begin, end):
    for count in range(begin, end):
        try:
            # something
            yield(...)

        except FileNotFoundError:
            continue
```

Comment: It raises an exception:  

    `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1528, in fit_generator
    str(generator_output))
ValueError: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None`  

Generator must be endless, because it must return same batch of data at the next epoch

Comment: "while" and "for" really have the same sence in while(True) & for(;;) -- therefore really there is no sence to use both... "while" in generator can be needed  when Tensors in batch could have different size (e.g. rows.count) - meaning non-equal-size, when we do not know borders for "for-loop"... usually such tensors are being padded later to be able participate in training... & generator itself yields a Dataset (of the same batch.size anyway, as yo like) - meaning set of such unequal tensors

Answer (score 0):

'yield' LAZILY & **asynchronously** outputs generated data while continuing to loop the same cycle! in generation_function (resuming where it is left off)... when you changed it to "return" - it is the exit from your generator_function, thus you'are starting read your csv_file from the beginning each time you're calling generator - therefore get the same results... you need "yield" to generate further data from your file... Well, but fit_generator is deprecated now - now use [fit](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/24/how-to-use-keras-fit-and-fit_generator-a-hands-on-tutorial/) - the idea of using "[yield](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-yield-keyword-instead-return-keyword-python/)" in all generators is the same... (even just [csv_reading](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) for simplicity)